# Windows Workflow - Web Service - App_Data Directory - Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, workflow

Solution
-- WorkflowProject
  -- Workflow1
  -- Workflow2
-- WebProject (WAP)
  -- App_Data
    -- MyDatabase.vdb3
  -- MyWebService.asmx
  -- Web.Config

Ok, so.. that's the basic "outline" of the project.
The database, is stored in the website, and is a VistaDB database (this could also be an MSAccess or SQLite Database).  In the website, I could code against the database.  I might have |DataDirectory| in my connection string.

The WORKFLOW project is separate from the Website.  The MyWebService.asmx is a "stub" for calling the Workflow based web service.

***How*** do I open the database in the website **App_Data** directory ?  Right now, I have the value hardcoded (i.e., @"E:\datadirectory\database.vdb3"), but this is not preferred and would only work on my development machine.

I can't even pass in the location of the database, since the webservice (the .asmx file) is only 1 line, and is stub code for getting the caller into the workflow.  I'm really at a loss as how to proceed.

Solution ?  Best practices ?  Links ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get VirtualPathUtility to work.  Here's the solution that I ended up finding that worked:

```
string s = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory") as string;
```

That gets the absolute path to the App_Data directory.

Comment: I'd be curious to see the code that you used with VirtualPathUtility, and what error you received, just for my own edification.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at "[VirtualPathUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.aspx)"

substitute the result of:

```
VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/App_Data/db.vdb3");
```

into your connection string.